# Do grunt tasks wait for previous tasks to finish?

Tags: gruntjs

When I call `shell:clean` at the end, it appears to delete the `~/tmp/<domain>` directory before the `shell:sync` task finishes. I'm missing files in the destination `~/www/versions/<domain>`.

The `shell:sync` tasks does an `rsync` command to copy files from `~/tmp` to `~/www`.

```
grunt.registerTask('deploy', 'Deploy web app', function(){
    grunt.task.run('shell:create_temp');

    //create version directories
    grunt.task.run('shell:create_version');
    grunt.task.run('shell:sync');

    //create symlink to live site
    grunt.task.run('shell:symlink');
    grunt.task.run('shell:clean');
});
```

Here is the config:

```
grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        cfg: _.extend(grunt.file.readJSON('config.json'), grunt.file.readJSON('config.'+env+'.json'), { env: env }),
        version_path: '<%= cfg.www_dir %>/versions/<%= cfg.domain %>@<%= pkg.version %>',
        tmp_site_path: '<%= cfg.tmp_dir %>/<%= cfg.domain %>',
        live_path: '<%= cfg.www_dir %>/<%= cfg.domain %>',
        shell: {
            create_temp: {
                command: 'mkdir -p <%= tmp_site_path %>',
                options: {
                    stdout: true,
                    stderr: true
                }
            },
            create_version: {
                command: 'mkdir -p <%= version_path %>',
                options: {
                    stdout: true,
                    stderr: true
                }
            },
            sync: {
                command: 'rsync -avz --delete --progress <%= tmp_site_path %>/ <%= version_path %>/',
                options: {
                    stdout: true,
                    stderr: true
                }
            },
            symlink: {
                command: 'rm <%= live_path %>; ln -sv <%= version_path %> <%= live_path %>',
                options: {
                    stdout: true,
                    stderr: true
                }
            },
            clean: {
                command: 'rm -rf <%= tmp_site_path %>',
                options: {
                    stdout: true,
                    stderr: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually tasks are run synchronously. But a plugin could bypass this - and this could be a bug in the plugin too.

Note though, that you'll usually combine taks this way:

```
grunt.registerTask("deploy", [
    'shell:create_temp',
    'shell:create_version',
    'shell:sync',
    'shell:symlink',
    'shell:clean'
]);
```

Comment: i tried that -- same effect. The `shell:clean` wiped out the tmp files before the `shell:sync` finished.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [grunt-bg-shell](https://github.com/rma4ok/grunt-bg-shell). It allows you to specify a callback for when tasks are finished running.

```
bgShell: {
  sync: {
    cmd: 'rsync -avz --delete --progress <%= tmp_site_path %>/ <%= version_path %>/',
    done: function () {
      grunt.task.run('shell:clean');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so are they not run syncronously?

Comment: Come to think of it I've never had a problem with longer running tasks using the shell plugin. Perhaps a better solution would be to use something like grunt-rsync instead. https://github.com/jedrichards/grunt-rsync

Comment: too much abstraction. I think the problem is `shell` didn't like all the output when using `-v` and eventually choked on it.

Comment: Fair enough, that makes sense. :)

Comment: `grunt-exec` will error out, `grunt-shell` seems to continue on (which isn't good imo).